# JMonkeyEngine with JDK 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, jmonkeyengine

I want to use lambda expressions, so i need JDK 8. I have set the project to JDK 8, in properties, but editor of the code gives errors when i use lambda. When trying to build it gives error like this:
`warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Test.java:17: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
        Runnable r = () -> System.out.println();
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)`
 So how to set JMonkeyEngine working on JDK 8?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the `-source 1.7` option when compiling your code? Are you using an IDE? Then configure it so that it regards your code as Java 8 code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To add to what @Jesper said, please edit your question to give us more details.  How are you compiling your code?  Are you using an IDE or a build tool such as Maven or Gradle?  The "-source 1.7" setting is coming from somewhere, and that is causing your problem.

Comment: The tangetial discussion on [this JMonkey thread](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/include-last-updated-date-on-the-download-page/) discusses using Java 8 with JMonkey - basically not available officially but may be possible by manually changing the JDK in the jmonkeyplatform.conf file

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to get Java 8 to work within the JMonkey IDE. However I was able to do it the  other way round; add JMonkey libraries to Netbeans 8.

- Install [Netbeans 8](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)

Then you follow the instructions [for adding JMonkey as a library to annother IDE](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:setting_up_jme3_in_eclipse). The instructions are for eclipse (as JMonkey IDE is based on Netbeans it would normally make no sense to do this).

- [Download the most recent build of JMonkey](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/sdk/releases)
- Unzip and save in your user directory
- Open Netbeans 8
- Either open an existing JMonkey project or Start a new project
- Open the project properties

  [image]
- Select to add JARs

  [image]
- Browse to where you saved the JMonkey build and open the lib folder

  [image]
- Select all the libraries and add them

  [image]

At this point it is now possible to create a JMonkey program using Java 8 code within Netbeans 8. However; the assets folder may still  be missing,
If you opened an existing project it will likely be there otherwise, again, we follow similar instructions within [Setting up JME3 in Eclipse](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:setting_up_jme3_in_eclipse) but its arguably easier in netbeans. Its pretty much identical to adding the JARs so I won't include screenshots.

- Open the project properties (again)
- Open the libraries tab
- Click add JAR/Folder
- Browse to assets folder
- Click open

Now you can run your project just as within the JMonkey IDE, using `AssetManager` to load assets. Of course you won't have all the nice JME specific features of JMonkey IDE.

**Note; [JMonkey is untested with Java 8](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/include-last-updated-date-on-the-download-page/#post-265058), I got a basic program to run, this does not guarantee success with a more complex program** (That said I have now used this technique to move my 500 class game across with zero issues; I love java)